# Get the category ID in checkout page woocomerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I try to unset Chash on delivery (`unset( $available_gateways['cod'] );`) in specific category.

So i need to get the category id of all product i select it in checkout page woocomerce.

How can do that!

Comment: to have a custom payement gateway, it's better to create a new one instead of modifying a existing one : https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/payment-gateway-api/

Answer (score 1):

Getting the ids of the items in your cart can be done somewhat like this:

```
global $woocommerce;
$cart = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
$cart_items_ids = array();
foreach ( $cart as $item_key => $item_value ) {
    $cart_items_ids[] = $item_value[ 'data' ]->id;
}
```

OR Plese check below Snippet: Check if Product Category is in the Cart – WooCommerce

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_cart', 'xyz_check_category_in_cart');

function xyz_check_category_in_cart() {
    // Set $cat_in_cart to false
    $cat_in_cart = false;

    // Loop through all products in the Cart        
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        $product = $cart_item['data'];

        // If Cart has category "download", set $cat_in_cart to true
        if ( has_term( 'download', 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ) {
            $cat_in_cart = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    // Do something if category "download" is in the Cart      
    if ( $cat_in_cart ) {

        // For example, print a notice
        wc_print_notice( 'Category Downloads is in the Cart!', 'notice' );

        // Or maybe run your own function...
    }
}
```

You can place PHP snippets at the bottom of your child theme functions.php file (before "?>" if you have it).

Please let me know in the comments if everything worked as expected.

Thank you!